# mod_rewrite Stop processing after specific rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

  RewriteRule ^viewuserimage/(.*) index.php?viewuserimage=$1 [L]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]


</IfModule>
```

Here you can see my .htaccess file. I want to rewrite all requests that start with viewuserimage/ to index.php?.., without processing the next rule. If I pass

```
/viewuserimage/test
```

It outputs:

```
index.php?page=index.php&viewuserimage=test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem, when you do the `viewuserimage` rule, you call `index.php?viewuserimage=$1`, so it will trigger again the .htaccess and the only rule left is the last one, so it will concatenate.

I can give you 2 solutions:

**FIRST ONE**

Change this

`RewriteRule ^viewuserimage/(.*) index.php?viewuserimage=$1 [L]`

To

`RewriteRule ^viewuserimage/(.*) index.php?viewuserimage=$1 [END]`

The `[END]` flag will STOP, is like a perma exit, not equal to `[L]`. [More info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)

**SECOND ONE**

Change this rule

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`

To

`RewriteRule ^(page1|page2|page3|pageAllowed)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`

In this rule, you tell which pages are allowed, so only this matches and goes to `index.php?page=$1`.

Comment: What now ? New answer

Comment: You mean the REQUEST_FILENAME conditions? If you do, it does not work.

Comment: Ok, let my try more in my linux server

Comment: I found the problem, when you do the `viewuserimage` rule, you call `index.php?viewuserimage=$1`, so it will trigger again the .htaccess and the only rule left is the last one, so it will concatenate. Read answer for more info.

Comment: As I am making a little content managing system for myself, the second solution isn't advisable for me, but the first one works fine. Thank you for you answer.